# Sitecore MVC Controller

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have "firstname" field in my view.
My question is how can manually add value or manipulate the field using my controller. 
Note: my view is already connected to Index.cshtml file and my controller name is FormsController

```
Firstname: @Html.Sitecore().Field("firstname")
```

Comment: Do you pass a model to your view? Before passing the model to your view, can you not get hold of the field value!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you'll be able to do what you need modifying the `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item`, but there are other variants available. Take a look on these few good posts describing the available options [here](http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-mvc-item-maze/) and [here](http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/sitecore-mvc-rendering-datasources).

Answer (score 0):

Either in your view assign @Html.Sitecore().Field("firstname") to a variable and do the logic in your view (not the best MVC approach).

```
@{
var firstName = Html.Sitecore().Field("firstname");
firstName = AddedCode + firstName;
}
Firstname:@firstName
```

Or in your controller create a partial class to extend your model that you are passing to the view with the already manipulated Firstname value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the item in Sitecore this is one way to do it, although you usually do not want to edit sitecore items from code:

```
        var sitecoreItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        sitecoreItem = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(sitecoreItem.ID);
        using (new EditContext(sitecoreItem, SecurityCheck.Disable))
        {
            sitecoreItem["Navigation title"] = "I have just Edited";
        }
```

Note that i first get the item and the get the item from the master db, since it would make little sense to edit the item from the web db.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from code you've provided, I mean this peace of code:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("firstname")
```

You want to manipulate with 'firstname' field of your context item.
If so all you need to do within appropriate action of your controller is something like this:

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    Sitecore.Context.Item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    try
    {
        Sitecore.Context.Item["firstname"] = "set value you want";      
        Sitecore.Context.Item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {       
        Sitecore.Context.Item.Editing.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

Note: using SecurityDisabler() means that your context user probably haven't permission for context item. So it just example. The best practice to grant appropriate access to necessary item using [The Security Editor](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/the_security_tools#_Security_Editor)